# Pydev 4.5.5 not a fit to Eclipse 4.5?

Tags: eclipse, installation, pydev

I have the proper pydev update link(http://pydev.org/updates) but it no longer installs. Instead I get the following when I try to update or install in eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars). Curiously there are ","'s it the urls (e.g. "osgi.bunder,com"... is that right?). Thanks for any help:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__eclipse-4.5_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,4.5.5.201603221110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,4.5.5.201603221110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,4.5.5.201603221110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,4.5.5.201603221110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,4.5.5.201603221110
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,4.5.5.201603221110

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the webpage the update site is pointing to has an issue?  If one goes to http://pydev.org/updates/ - the website displayed shows the message: "Nothing to see here (this is just a dummy link to be redirected to https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.5.0)".  Updating eclipse and setting the site location to https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.5.0 I was able to pull the updates.  Looking at the wayback machine, as late as Dec 2016 the http://pydev.org/updates/ redirected to https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.4.0, so the destination website seems to be correct.